# Tags fail to display inside blockquotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, blockquote

#### Example 1:

```
> [tag:bug]
```

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Example 2:

```
<blockquote> [tag:bug] </blockquote>
```

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

It doesn't show inside `<code>` tag as well, but I don't know if it is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intentional in `<code>`, but was a mistake on my part in `<blockquote>`.

This has been fixed in dev, and should be deployed sometime later today.